# Using C string handling functions like strchr or memchr to parse char array into C++ key value map

Tags: c++, c-strings

I have a char array like this:

```
"CA: ABCD\0CB: ABFG\0CC: AFBV\0CD: 4567"
```

Now `": "` splits key from value while `\0` separates the pairs. I want to add the key-value pairs to a map in C++ using strchr or memchr functions. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have a suggestion. Show the map declaration.:)

Comment: How do you plan to know where the string ends? In other words, how are you going to determine which pair is the last one?

Comment: I just need to add keys and values i get into a StringStringMap I have defined something like "values.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(parsedKey, parsedValue))"

Comment: After every value there is a null termination

Comment: Precisely. So, after encountering a NUL terminator, how do you know whether to stop or to keep looking for the next pair?

Comment: Since the key-value pairs are terminated by a string terminator character, all you need is a pointer to the "current" position and `strcpy` (if you want to continue using old C functions).

Comment: As for the problem of finding the actual end of the string, are you showing the actual data you have? There's not an extra terminator after the last entry, so the end is found by having two consecutive terminators?

Comment: No just a single terminator

Comment: Then the only way to know the actual end is if you have the length of the full string.

Comment: Yes the length is there. I want to know how the implementation is done by using these two functions

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
const char source[] = "CA: ABCD\0CB: ABFG\0CC: AFBV\0CD: 4567";
int len = sizeof(source);
std::map<std::string, std::string> pairs;

const char* end = source + len;
const char* start = source;
while (start < end) {
    const char* sep = strchr(start, ':');
    const char* pair_end = strchr(sep + 2, '\0');
    pairs.emplace(std::string(start, sep), std::string(sep + 2, pair_end));
    start = pair_end + 1;
}
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/IGKUDH23972)

Comment: I need to insert values into a map. Something like values.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(parsedKey, parsedValue)). What does emplace do?

Comment: What [the fine manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) says it does. If you insist, replacing an `emplace` call with an equivalent `insert` call is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: But this piece of code will never cause a heap violation right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: I meant if any check can be added before incrementing.

Comment: Well, my code assumes, and never verifies, that the string is in the expected format. If it isn't, the code would likely crash. Any checks and error handling necessary to deal with possibly-malformed input are left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: How can I convert this while into an equivalent for loop?

Comment: Why would you want to? Though a `for` loop could be shoehorned into the task, a `while` is much more natural here. But if you insist: `for (const char* start = source, *end = source + len; start < end; ) { ... }`

Comment: Also, `start = pair_end + 1` can go inside `for` loop right?

Comment: It would have to. Where else could it be?